# How can I get cmd result using php

Tags: php, cmd, lucene

i am using this code in php for using lucene file indexer and searcher but it results in empty array...

```
$resul = exec('set classpath=C:\lucene\lucene\core\lucene-core-4.3.0.jar;C:\lucene\lucene\queryparser\lucene-queryparser-4.3.0.jar;C:\lucene\lucene\analysis\common\lucene-analyzers-common-4.3.0.jar;C:\lucene\lucene\demo\lucene-demo-4.3.0.jar2>&1',$result);
echo $result;
$resul = exec('java org.apache.lucene.demo.IndexFiles -doc C:\lucene\src',$result);
echo $result;
$resul = exec('java org.apache.lucene.demo.SearchFiles');
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 1):

Each instance of `exec` uses a separate environment from all the others. This means that the environment variables set by your first `exec` do not "stick" when the following calls are made, so the classpath is most likely empty and your Java programs fail to run.

The solution is to make everything into one big command line. On Windows you can do that by concatenating the commands with `&`:

```
// Sorry for the unreadable line, but it has to be without linebreaks
$commands = "set classpath=C:\lucene\lucene\core\lucene-core-4.3.0.jar;C:\lucene\lucene\queryparser\lucene-queryparser-4.3.0.jar;C:\lucene\lucene\analysis\common\lucene-analyzers-common-4.3.0.jar;C:\lucene\lucene\demo\lucene-demo-4.3.0.jar2 & java org.apache.lucene.demo.IndexFiles -doc C:\lucene\src & java org.apache.lucene.demo.SearchFiles";

exec($commands, $result);
```

With this arrangement `$result` will only contain the output from the *last* command run, but fortunately this looks like exactly what you want to do.